# Как VDS понимает что куда кидать?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, vds

Предположим возьмем стандартный пример: VDS на Ubuntu и установленным Докером. Там крутится 3 контейнера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В компосах у каждого прописано, что если стучатся на:

- 190.190.190.190:81 - то отрабатывает 1ый контейнер
- 190.190.190.190:82 - то отрабатывает 2ой контейнер
- 190.190.190.190:83 - то отрабатывает 3ий контейнер

**Теперь сам вопрос:**

Как VDS понимает куда отправлять запросы? Ведь в

> cd /etc/nginx/sites-available/

не прописаны никакие маршруты...

Или получается, что демон Докера сам берет на себя роль Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Грубо говоря это проброс портов с localhost в контейнер Docker'a. К примеру:
можно назначить 81 порт адреса 190.190.190.190 к 80 порту контейнера №1 (при запуске из терминала  `docker run -d -p 81:80` или указав это в своём Dockerfile)

Comment: Получается, что докер может выполнять роль веб-сервера?

Comment: Нет, но вы можете установить веб-сервер в каждый запущенный контейнер. По этой ссылке (https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) официальная документация по вашему вопросу

Comment: Не - Вы меня не поняли. Посмотрите на рисунок в вопросе: там уже в каждом контейнере стоит веб-сервер NGINX, которые слушает порт и отправляет его на свои порты работающего контейнера, на которых есть какой-нибудь APP. Я просто задался вопросом а как VDS понимает, что куда кидать? Ведь на нем же не стоит отдельный веб-сервер, который слушает входящие и распределяет по входящие на контейнеры. Получается, что на VDS докер-демон выполняет эту функцию? Типа слушает все порты и сравнивает есть ли описание у него в контейнерах и если есть то типа пускает на определенный контейнер. Так получается?